# Reference to local Arc that lives beyond the function

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am using the [vulkano](https://docs.rs/vulkano/0.6/vulkano) library that has the two types:

- [`Instance`](https://docs.rs/vulkano/0.6/vulkano/instance/struct.Instance.html)
- [`PhysicalDevice`](https://docs.rs/vulkano/0.5/vulkano/instance/struct.PhysicalDevice.html)

`PhysicalDevice` takes an `&Arc<Instance>`. I am writing a function that returns a struct containing an `Arc` to instances to these classes, but, due to the fact that [`PhysicalDevice::enumerate`](https://docs.rs/vulkano/0.5/vulkano/instance/struct.PhysicalDevice.html#method.enumerate) requires an `&Arc<Instance>`, the borrow checker is not compiling the code, even if the instances live beyond the function.

I've created a smaller reproduction of the problem where `Pet` takes a `&Arc<Person>`.

In the function `test`, I create both objects and try to return them in a struct:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

struct Person {
    name: String,
}

struct Pet<'t> {
    name: String,
    owner: &'t Arc<Person>,
}

struct PersonPetPair<'a> {
    person: Arc<Person>,
    pet: Arc<Pet<'a>>,
}

fn test<'a>() -> PersonPetPair<'a> {
    let person = Person {
        name: String::from("ash"),
    };
    let person_arc = Arc::new(person);

    let pet = Pet {
        name: String::from("pikachu"),
        owner: &person_arc,
    };
    let pet_arc = Arc::new(pet);

    PersonPetPair {
        person: person_arc,
        pet: pet_arc,
    }
    // person_arc ends here, so the reference is invalid anymore
    // Still, the objects are still alive since they are created with
    // Arc<>
}

fn main() {
    let t = test();
    println!("{} owns {}", t.person.name, t.pet.name);
}
```

The compiler tells me there is a problem:

```
error[E0597]: `person_arc` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:25:17
   |
25 |         owner: &person_arc,
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
36 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 17:9...
  --> src/main.rs:17:9
   |
17 | fn test<'a>() -> PersonPetPair<'a> {
   |         ^^
```

Indeed, the local variable `person_arc` is being dropped when the function ends. There should be a way to avoid this problem since both instances outlive the function thanks to the use of `Arc`.

Comment: The entire reason to use an `Arc` is so that you can have multiple owners. [Don't save a reference to the `Arc`, just clone it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b57d16849bb603324f337727793020ff&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015). When you call `PhysicalDevice::new`, take the reference there.

Comment: @Shepmaster the method enumerate(), which I use, is indeed taking a reference

https://docs.rs/vulkano/0.5/vulkano/instance/struct.PhysicalDevice.html#method.enumerate

isn't this the problem?

Comment: I don't follow your question. You cannot store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct, as described in the duplicate. Thus you cannot store an `Arc<Instance>` and a `PhysicalDevice` that references it in the same struct. In the code you have provided here, you can change it to keep whole `Arc`s, not references; perhaps you can change the library. The type `&Arc<T>` is suspicious on the surface, honestly. Otherwise, there's really no reason to keep the `PhysicalDevice` struct around; it's super lightweight to create.

Comment: Note that the code I provided is used for reproducing the problem of the library, which of course I cannot change. 
The question is: Due to the fact that I cannot change the library, and creating a struct in the way I tried does not work, what is the proper way to include both Instance and PhysicalDevice in a unique object? 
What I want to achieve is to have a class that 'hides' the vulkan stuff, so I want to put the Vulkan variables in there. Or I am supposed to carry around multiple objects through my program?

Comment: Thanks for the linked question, it is really useful for understanding the problem.

Comment: *of course I cannot change* — I don't see why not, it's an open-source project that presumably accepts pull requests. However, we cannot answer hypothetical questions about code that isn't provided. *what is the proper way to include both `Instance` and `PhysicalDevice` in a unique object* — that's what the section labeled **How do I fix it?** in the linked question is all about. I also suggested: *there's really no reason to keep the `PhysicalDevice` struct around; it's super lightweight to create*.

Comment: I am checking this https://github.com/vulkano-rs/vulkano/issues/930